# How can I simulate Health-Monitor Events in VxWorks 653 2.5.0.2?

Tags: c++, vxworks, rtos

I'm new to [RTOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rtos) as a whole, and to [WindRiver's](https://www.windriver.com/) [VxWorks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vxworks) particulary.

I come from a Java background, and making my first steps into enterprise RTOS embedded systems.
Currently, I'm working on [VxWorks 653 2.5.0.2](https://www.windriver.com/products/product-notes/vxworks-653-product-note/vxworks-653-product-note.pdf).

My first task, is to configure the Module.xml file (see attached image) with the relevant Health-Monitoring tables (system, partition and module - see section 5 in [this document](https://www.windriver.com/products/platforms/safety_critical/12_Reasons_VE653.pdf)).
After configuring it, I noticed I don't really know how to **test** it.

Sure, I can probably "simulate" an `HME_NUMERIC_ERROR` by diving by zero, but **I'm trying to find some better way to simulate these tests.**

A best approach, in my POV, will be to have some **shell command** in the VxWorks shell, that **injects** Health Monitor Events by demand. Something like [these](http://read.pudn.com/downloads152/ebook/661129/VxWorks%20commands.pdf) commands.

Any thoughts about shell commands or best-practices to approach this, would be great.

Hope you guys can help me,
Thanks!

**Module.xml file example (taken from [here](https://docs.adacore.com/gnatbench_for_windriver-docs/src/debugging/preparing_to_debug_653.html)):**

[image: module.xml]

**Health Monitor Table example (Scavenged from [here](https://vxworks653.blogspot.co.il/2014/06/vxworks-653-health-monitor.html) - what language is that?!):**

```
<PartitionHMTable Name="partition1Hm">
 <SystemState>
  <ErrorIDAction Error Identifier="HME_UNKNOWN" ErrorAction="hmDefaultHandler"/>
  <ErrorIDAction Error Identifier="HME_NUMERIC_ERROR" ErrorAction=""/>
  <ErrorIDAction Error Identifier="HME_POWER_FAIL" ErrorAction="hmDH_HME_POWER_FAIL"/>
  <ErrorIDAction Error Identifier="HME_KERNEL" ErrorAction="hmDH_HME_KERNEL"/>
  <ErrorIDAction Error Identifier="HME_CONFIG_ERROR" ErrorAction="hmDH_EventLog"/>
  <ErrorIDAction Error Identifier="HME_INIT_ERROR" ErrorAction="hmDH_HME_INIT_ERROR"/>
  <ErrorIDAction Error Identifier="HME_PARTITION_OVERFLOW" ErrorAction="hmDefaultHandler"/>
  <ErrorIDAction Error Identifier="HME_PARTITION_MODE_SET" ErrorAction="hmDH_HME_PARTITION_MODE_SET"/>
  <ErrorIDAction Error Identifier="HME_APEX_INTERNAL_ERROR" ErrorAction="hmDefaultHandler"/>
  <ErrorIDAction Error Identifier="HME_HM_INTERNAL_ERROR" ErrorAction="hmDefaultHandler"/>
  <ErrorIDAction Error Identifier="HME_PORT_INTERNAL_ERROR" ErrorAction="hmDefaultHandler"/>
  <ErrorIDAction Error Identifier="HME_LOST_TICKS" ErrorAction="hmDM_LOST_TICKS"/>
  <ErrorIDAction Error Identifier="HME_HM_ERROR" ErrorAction="hmDefaultHandler"/>
  <ErrorIDAction Error Identifier="HME_HMQ_OVERFLOW" ErrorAction="hmDefaultHandler"/>
  <ErrorIDAction Error Identifier="HME_DATA_LOSS" ErrorAction=""/>
   <ErrorIDAction Error Identifier="HME_HM_DEADLINE_MISSED" ErrorAction="hmDefaultHandler"/>
  <ErrorIDAction Error Identifier="HM_MSG" ErrorAction="hmDH_EventLog"/>
  <ErrorIDAction Error Identifier="HME_DEFAULT" ErrorAction=""/>
 <Settings maxQueueDepth="34" queueThresHold="32" stackSize="16384" maxLogEntries="100" logEntriesThreshold="98" attributesMask="0x00000001" notificationHandler ="" notificationMaxQueueDepth="0" eventFilterMask="0xFFFFFFFF" maxErrorHandlerQueueDepth="128" errorHandlerQueueThreshold="126"
  </Settings>
  </SystemState>
</PartitionHMTable>
```

Comment: I used to work with pretty old VxWorks version, but it didn't have term "shell command". Shell was kind of C interpreter, so it could execute any global C function. Some of them (memShow, sp and others) were implemented in system libraries, but I was free to call any function I implemented myself in global scope. I wonder if it's still true for your case, and if yes, how it can be performed from Java perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out VxWorks have a designated function for this: `HM_EVENT_INJECT` which can be used if you include the `hmLib.h` file in your application code.

Here is a small sample of the code I wrote, simplified for clarity:

```
void HMEInject(int strLength, char* errorString) {
    switch (choice) {
    case 1:
        //HME_DEADLINE_MISSED
        HM_EVENT_INJECT(HME_DEADLINE_MISSED, HM_SUB_CODE_STRING, 0, strLength,
                (char * ) errorString);
        break;
    case 2:
        //HME_APPLICATION_ERROR
        HM_EVENT_INJECT(HME_APPLICATION_ERROR, HM_SUB_CODE_STRING, 0, strLength,
                (char * ) errorString);
        break;
    case 3:
        //HME_NUMERIC_ERROR
        HM_EVENT_INJECT(HME_NUMERIC_ERROR, HM_SUB_CODE_STRING, 0, strLength,
                (char * ) errorString);
        break;
    case 4:
        //HME_ILLEGAL_REQUEST
        HM_EVENT_INJECT(HME_ILLEGAL_REQUEST, HM_SUB_CODE_STRING, 0, strLength,
                (char * ) errorString);
        break;

        ...
    }
 }
```

Note that all of the `HM_CODE`s can be used after including the `hmTypes.h` file.

Snippet from `hmTypes.h`:

```
enum HM_CODE
    {  

    /* ARINC 653 defined codes */

    HME_DEADLINE_MISSED = 0,    /* first ARINC code must be 0 */
    HME_APPLICATION_ERROR,
    HME_NUMERIC_ERROR,
    HME_ILLEGAL_REQUEST,
    HME_STACK_OVERFLOW,
    HME_MEMORY_VIOLATION,
    HME_HARDWARE_FAULT,
    HME_POWER_FAIL,

    ...

    }
```

**Clarification:**

1. Did not test this code on our target OS yet.
2. These injections will work on `Process Level` via the **Partition** Health-Monitoring table only. For `Kernel Level` (via the **Module** Health-Monitoring table), please use the same command on the VxWorks Terminal.